# Charts not displayed in django admin view?

Tags: javascript, python, django, charts

I am trying to display some charts in my admin view( by extending admin/base.html) and I want to use a template instead of libraries such as charts.Js to display them. I want my view to be like the following (https://colorlib.com/polygon/cooladmin/index.html). Github repo here (https://github.com/puikinsh/CoolAdmin). However, in my case no charts are being displayed.

I have integrated all files and folders( containing static files) and set all dependencies correctly andhe main.js(contains code for charts) are also working.

Extract from main.html(includes links)

```
<div id="content-main" class="main-content container-fluid">
    <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="overview-wrap">
                        <h2 class="title-1">overview</h2>
                        <button class="au-btn au-btn-icon au-btn--blue">
                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i>add item</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row m-t-25">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="overview-item overview-item--c1">
                        <div class="overview__inner">
                            <div class="overview-box clearfix">
                                <div class="icon">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-o"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text">
                                    <h2>10368</h2>
                                    <span>members online</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="overview-chart">
                                <canvas id="widgetChart1"></canvas>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <!-- Jquery JS-->
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}""></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS-->
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/bootstrap-4.1/popper.min.js' %}""></script>
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.js' %}""></script>
    <!-- Vendor JS       -->
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/slick/slick.min.js' %}"">
    </script>
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/wow/wow.min.js' %}""></script>
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/animsition/animsition.min.js' %}""></script>
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js' %}"">
    </script>
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/counter-up/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}""></script>
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/counter-up/jquery.counterup.min.js' %}"">
    </script>
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/circle-progress/circle-progress.min.js' %}""></script>
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.js' %}""></script>
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/chartjs/Chart.bundle.min.js' %}""></script>
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/vendor/select2/select2.min.js' %}"">
    </script>
        <!-- Main JS-->
    <script src={% static 'hfs_admin/js_template/main.js' %}></script>
```

Extract from main.js

```
(function ($) {
  // USE STRICT
  "use strict";

  try {
    //WidgetChart 1
    var ctx = document.getElementById("widgetChart1");
    if (ctx) {
      ctx.height = 130;
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
          type: 'line',
          datasets: [{
            data: [78, 81, 80, 45, 34, 12, 40],
            label: 'Dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.55)',
          },]
        },
        options: {
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          layout: {
            padding: {
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0
            }
          },
          responsive: true,
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                color: 'transparent',
                zeroLineColor: 'transparent'
              },
              ticks: {
                fontSize: 2,
                fontColor: 'transparent'
              }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              display: false,
              ticks: {
                display: false,
              }
            }]
          },
          title: {
            display: false,
          },
          elements: {
            line: {
              borderWidth: 0
            },
            point: {
              radius: 0,
              hitRadius: 10,
              hoverRadius: 4
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Expected ouput should be like the following (https://colorlib.com/polygon/cooladmin/index.html). However mine gets rendered without any charts. I beleive something is preventing the JS from applying the chart onto the html page.

Any helps will be appreciated. Also Do let me know if the question need updating. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: it uses chart.js.
https://www.chartjs.org/
You will have to have a js file with datapoints.
Try opening the chrome developer console and inspect the js.